# Show that $(P(\mathbb{R}))'$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$are isomorphic vector spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I tried to prove this statement, however, I am not sure that what I did (mostly in step **(2)**) is correct.
I am a complete beginner in proof writing and I may be doing fundamental methodological mistakes.

**Claim:**

> Show that $(P(\mathbb{R}))'$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$are isomorphic
> vector spaces.

**Proof:**

Define a linear map $\Gamma:\mathcal{L}(P(\mathbb{R}),F)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$
such that $\Gamma\psi=(\psi(1),\psi(x),\psi(x^{2}),...).$

Observe that,

$\Gamma0=(0,...)=0$

$\Gamma(\lambda f)=(\lambda f(1),\lambda f(x),...)=\lambda(f(1),f(x),...)=\lambda\Gamma f$

$\Gamma(f+g)=(f(1)+g(1),f(x)+g(x),...)=(f(1),f(x),...)+(g(1),g(x),...)=\Gamma f+\Gamma g$

Hence, $\Gamma$ is a linear map.

To show that $\Gamma$ is an isomorphism, we need to show
that it is injective **(1)** and surjective **(2)**.

**(1)** Say $\Gamma$ is not injective, i.e. $\exists\psi\in\mathcal{L}(P(\mathbb{R}),F)$
such that $\Gamma\psi=0$ with $\psi\neq0$.

Then, $\psi(x^{n})=0,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Consider a polynomial $k=a_{0}+a_{1}x+...\in P(\mathbb{R})$.

Since $\psi$ is a linear map, $\psi k=\psi(a_{0}+a_{1}x+...)=a_{0}\psi(1)+a_{1}\psi(x)+...=0.$

Note that $\psi k=0,\forall k\in P(\mathbb{R})$ implies that $\psi=0$
which is a contradiction.

Therefore $\Gamma$ is injective.

**(2)** Suppose $\Gamma$ is not surjective, i.e. $\exists a\in\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$
s.t $\Gamma f\neq a,\forall f\in\mathcal{L}(P(\mathbb{R}),F)$.

Define $\{p_{n}\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ such that $p_{n}=a_{n}$ with $a=(a_{0},a_{1},...)$.

Consider the linear functional $f:P(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow F$ such
that $f(x^{n})=p_{n}$.

Finally, observe that $\Gamma f=a$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore $\Gamma$ is surjective.

Since $\Gamma$ is an isomorphism, $(P(\mathbb{R}))'$ and $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$are
isomorphic vector spaces.

Comment: What is $(P(\mathbb R))'$, the (algebraic) dual of the space of polynomials? Also, what is $\mathbb R^\infty$ (do you mean a direct sum or a direct product of copies of $\mathbb R$, different when the dimension is infinite)? From the map you construct it looks like a direct product, in a sum you can only have finitely many non-zero coefficients).

Comment: $(P(\mathbb{R}))' \text{ denotes } \mathcal{L}(P(\mathbb{R}),F)$ and the latter denotes a direct product, I think... I am not sure of my understanding of the term "direct product", but here $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is understood as the infinite dimensional vector space containing elements $v=(v_1,v_2,...)$ with $v_n\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: This is mostly fine, but:
1) I'd re-word the last two proofs to be direct proofs rather than proof by contradiction.  You just need to remove a few words.
2) In the proof of surjectivity, why make a new symbol $p_n$ when it is already equal to $a_n$?
3) It would look better if you centered some of your equations using (use $$ instead of $) and remove line breaks between some of the sentences so you can see the paragraphs.

Comment: I assume you meant to write $\mathbb R$ where you wrote $F$

Comment: In fact one has an isomorphism of topological vector spaces.

Comment: @doetoe Not exactly, in Axler's _Linear Algebra Done Right_, F denotes $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @JairTaylor are proofs by contradiction generally considered to be less rigorous or elegant than direct proofs? For some reasons I always think by contradiction...

Comment: @Julia Less rigorous, no. Less elegant, maybe.  In general shorter proofs are considered more elegant, and in this case you can make them a bit shorter with direct proofs.  It's a bit subjective, but I suspect most mathematicians would agree.